# greater than equal condition for filtering nested json in rethinkdb doesn't work

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I have below json rows in rethinkdb table.

```
[{"pid": 0,
"sk": [
{
"sid": 30,
"et": 3
},
{
"sid": 22,
"et": 10
},
{
"sid": 30,
"et": 10
}
],
"wc": [
 {
 "wid": 29,
 "et": 8
 },
 {
  "wid": 30,
  "et": 2
 },
 ],
 "dom": [
 {
  "did": 7,
  "et": 2
 }
 ],
 "ex": 17,
 "av": 12,
 "lc": "FRA"
  }
```

Am trying to filter sk fields for those sid's et values are greater than equal to the input values.

I tried below code, it doesn't work

```
r.db('mc').table('f_tab').getField('pid').filter(
  r.row(
  [{['sk']['sid']=21,['sk']['et'] > 5},{...}]
 )
)
```

Please note that sk field may contain upto 10 rows

After filtering, I want to again apply filter on resultant dataset for ['wc'] as well (for ge)

what am I missing ?

Comment: Try to change = to ==, ['sk']['sid'] == 21

Comment: Hi,  I tried it and it fails with "Typeerror: list indices must be integer, not str". So, I used filter(r.row([{['sk'][0]['sid']==21,['sk'][0]['et'] > 5}])).run(t) .. This still fails with error "String indices must be integers"